# CouchDB View - Filter and Group By on Key Array

Tags: group-by, couchdb, view, filtering

#### Description of Problem

I have an array of keys in a CouchDB view, `[doc.time, doc.address]`. Neither is unique. `doc.time` is a UNIX timestamp and `doc.address` is a string. The `reduce` function is set to `_sum` as the only value for each set of keys is a number.

What I want is to filter by `doc.time`, then group the remaining records by `doc.address`. If I put `doc.time` as the first key, I cannot seem to group by unique addresses no matter what I specify as a `group_level`. If I put `doc.address` first, I cannot seem to filter the query by time.

#### Two Examples

Query: `?group_level=1&startkey=[0,1230000000]&endkey=[{},1340000000]`

First Key: `doc.address` before `doc.time`

Problem: Does not filter by time

Code:

```
rows: [
  {
    key: [ "1126GDuGLQTX3LFHHmjCctdn8WKDjn7QNA" ],
    value: 50
  },
  {
    key: [ "112AobLhjLJQ3LGqXFrsdnWMPqWCQqoiS6" ],
    value: 50
  }
]
```

---

Query: `?group_level=1&startkey=[1230000000]&endkey=[1340000000,{}]`

First Key: `doc.time` before `doc.address`

Problem: Cannot see and I am not grouped by `doc.address`

Code:

```
rows: [
  {
    key: [ 1231469665 ],
    value: 50
  },
  {
    key: [ 1231469744 ],
    value: 50
  }
]
```

Comment: Did you take a look at [this explanation](https://blog.couchbase.com/understanding-grouplevel-view-queries-compound-keys/ "Understanding group_level in View Queries with Compound Keys")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned that:

> ... If I put `doc.time` as the first key, I cannot seem to group by unique addresses no matter what I specify as a group_level ...

The query parameter `group_level=N` splits the string on the `Nth` comma and groups the left elements together by string match. Therefore, When your *array key* is like this: `[doc.time, doc.address]`, you won't be able to group by `address`, which is not on the left side of the comma.

> ... If I put `doc.address` first, I cannot seem to filter the query by time ...

When your *array key* is like: `[doc.address, doc.time]`, notice that you are emitting an *array key* inside your Map function. You need to consider the **following points** regarding *array key* or *compound key* in CouchDB:

---

Described on [this reference](https://blog.couchbase.com/understanding-grouplevel-view-queries-compound-keys/):

> ... First thing of note and *very* important ... an array output ... from the javascript Map function ... each of those Index Keys are strings, and are ordered character by character as strings, including the brackets and commas ...

The above statement and explanations on [the reference](https://blog.couchbase.com/understanding-grouplevel-view-queries-compound-keys/) have a significant impact on how CouchDB indexing works in the case of *compound key* or *array key*.

To clarify, lets create documents like below on a `sample` database:

```
{"time":"2011","address":"CT"}
{"time":"2012","address":"CT"}
...
{"time":"2011","address":"TX"}
...
{"time":"2015","address":"TX"}
...
{"time":"2014","address":"NY"}
...
{"time":"2014","address":"CA"}
{"time":"2015","address":"CA"}
{"time":"2016","address":"CA"}
```

I implemented a view map function like this:

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.time && doc.address){
    emit([doc.address, doc.time], null);
  }
}
```

For now, I'm not using any *Reduce* function, because, lets ignore any *grouping* or *reducing* and focus on plain simple **indexing**. The above view is generating the following key/value pairs for indexing:

```
$ curl -k -X GET 'https://admin:****@192.168.1.106:6984/sample/_design/by_addr_time/_view/by_addr_time'
{"total_rows":25,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"doc_0022","key":["CA","2014"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0023","key":["CA","2015"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0024","key":["CA","2016"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0000","key":["CT","2011"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0001","key":["CT","2012"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0002","key":["CT","2013"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0003","key":["CT","2014"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0004","key":["CT","2015"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0005","key":["CT","2016"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0014","key":["NY","2011"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0015","key":["NY","2012"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0016","key":["NY","2013"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0017","key":["NY","2014"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0018","key":["NY","2015"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0019","key":["NY","2016"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0020","key":["NY","2017"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0021","key":["NY","2018"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0006","key":["TX","2011"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0008","key":["TX","2012"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0007","key":["TX","2013"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0009","key":["TX","2014"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0010","key":["TX","2015"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0011","key":["TX","2016"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0012","key":["TX","2017"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0013","key":["TX","2018"],"value":null}
]}
```

Now, I'm going to do a query to filter the view by `doc.time`. My query parameters are:

```
?startkey=["AA","2017"]&endkey=["ZZ","2018"]
```

I expect the above query to return only the docs with the `time` field between `2017` and `2018`, the `address` field of those docs can have **any** value since I specified from `AA` to `ZZ` which includes all addresses on my database. I'm doing the query with `curl` like this:

```
$ curl -k -X GET 'https://admin:****@192.168.1.106:6984/sample/_design/by_addr_time/_view/by_addr_time?startkey=\["AA","2017"\]&endkey=\["ZZ","2018"\]'
{"total_rows":25,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"doc_0022","key":["CA","2014"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0023","key":["CA","2015"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0024","key":["CA","2016"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0000","key":["CT","2011"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0001","key":["CT","2012"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0002","key":["CT","2013"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0003","key":["CT","2014"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0004","key":["CT","2015"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0005","key":["CT","2016"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0014","key":["NY","2011"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0015","key":["NY","2012"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0016","key":["NY","2013"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0017","key":["NY","2014"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0018","key":["NY","2015"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0019","key":["NY","2016"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0020","key":["NY","2017"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0021","key":["NY","2018"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0006","key":["TX","2011"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0008","key":["TX","2012"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0007","key":["TX","2013"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0009","key":["TX","2014"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0010","key":["TX","2015"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0011","key":["TX","2016"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0012","key":["TX","2017"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0013","key":["TX","2018"],"value":null}
]}
```

The response returned by the above query seems **shocking**. Because it looks like it did NOT return only the docs with `time` filed between `2017` and `2018`. That's just how the CouchDB indexing for *array keys* work. **CouchDB does the indexing of *array keys* as if the whole array is a string including the brackets and commas of the array!** If you read [the reference](https://blog.couchbase.com/understanding-grouplevel-view-queries-compound-keys/), it would start to make sense.

Now lets change the query:

```
?startkey=["CT","2016"]&endkey=["TX","2011"]
```

The result of the above query is shown below, based on our explanations, this should make sense:

```
$ curl -k -X GET 'https://admin:****@192.168.1.106:6984/sample/_design/by_addr_time/_view/by_addr_time?startkey=\["CT","2016"\]&endkey=\["TX","2011"\]'
{"total_rows":25,"offset":8,"rows":[
{"id":"doc_0005","key":["CT","2016"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0014","key":["NY","2011"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0015","key":["NY","2012"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0016","key":["NY","2013"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0017","key":["NY","2014"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0018","key":["NY","2015"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0019","key":["NY","2016"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0020","key":["NY","2017"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0021","key":["NY","2018"],"value":null},
{"id":"doc_0006","key":["TX","2011"],"value":null}
]}
```

---

### UPDATE

> ... What I want is to filter by `doc.time`, then group the remaining records by `doc.address` ...

So, what should we do? There is a good [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4513255/3405291) and provides the basic ideas.

I'm **not sure** which idea is the best, but I implemented one idea like this: created a view named `t_red` like below with a builtin `_count` reduce:

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.time && doc.address){
    emit([doc.time, doc.address], null);
  }
}
```

Also, I created a view named `a_red` with a builtin `_count` reduce:

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.address && doc.time){
    emit([doc.address, doc.time], null);
  }
}
```

Then I developed the following code on **NodeJS** to query `doc.time` between `2012` and `2015` and then group the results according to the `doc.address`, console logs are shown inside the code  as comments. I hope this code will be helpful (not confusing!):

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"; // Ignore rejection, becasue CouchDB SSL certificate is self-signed

const fetch=require('node-fetch')

// query "t_red" view/index
fetch(`https://admin:****@192.168.1.106:6984/sample/_design/t_red/_view/t_red?group_level=2&startkey=["2012", "AA"]&endkey=["2015", "ZZ"]`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
}).then(
    res=>res.json()
).then(data=>{
    let unique_addr=[]
    data.rows.map(row=>{
        console.log('row.key-> ', row.key, '  row.value-> ', row.value)

        // console log is shown below:
        //
        // row.key->  [ '2012', 'CT' ]   row.value->  1
        // row.key->  [ '2012', 'NY' ]   row.value->  1
        // row.key->  [ '2012', 'TX' ]   row.value->  1
        // row.key->  [ '2013', 'CT' ]   row.value->  1
        // row.key->  [ '2013', 'NY' ]   row.value->  1
        // row.key->  [ '2013', 'TX' ]   row.value->  1
        // row.key->  [ '2014', 'CA' ]   row.value->  1
        // row.key->  [ '2014', 'CT' ]   row.value->  1
        // row.key->  [ '2014', 'NY' ]   row.value->  1
        // row.key->  [ '2014', 'TX' ]   row.value->  1
        // row.key->  [ '2015', 'CA' ]   row.value->  1
        // row.key->  [ '2015', 'CT' ]   row.value->  1
        // row.key->  [ '2015', 'NY' ]   row.value->  1
        // row.key->  [ '2015', 'TX' ]   row.value->  1

        if(unique_addr.indexOf(row.key[1])==-1){ // Push unique addresses into an array
            unique_addr.push(row.key[1])
        }
    })

    console.log(unique_addr)

    // Console log is shown below:
    //
    // [ 'CT', 'NY', 'TX', 'CA' ]

    return unique_addr

}).then(unique_addr=>{

    // Group the unique addresses
    let group_by_address=unique_addr.map(addr=>{
        // For each unique address, do a query of "a_red" view/index
        return fetch(`https://admin:****@192.168.1.106:6984/sample/_design/a_red/_view/a_red?group_level=2&startkey=["${addr}","2012"]&endkey=["${addr}","2015"]`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        }).then(
            res=>res.json()
        ).then(data=>{
            data.rows.map(row=>{console.log('row.key-> ', row.key, '  row.value-> ', row.value)})

            // Console logs related to this section of code are shown below

            //row.key->  [ 'CA', '2014' ]   row.value->  1
            //row.key->  [ 'CA', '2015' ]   row.value->  1

            //row.key->  [ 'NY', '2012' ]   row.value->  1
            //row.key->  [ 'NY', '2013' ]   row.value->  1
            //row.key->  [ 'NY', '2014' ]   row.value->  1
            //row.key->  [ 'NY', '2015' ]   row.value->  1

            //row.key->  [ 'CT', '2012' ]   row.value->  1
            //row.key->  [ 'CT', '2013' ]   row.value->  1
            //row.key->  [ 'CT', '2014' ]   row.value->  1
            //row.key->  [ 'CT', '2015' ]   row.value->  1

            //row.key->  [ 'TX', '2012' ]   row.value->  1
            //row.key->  [ 'TX', '2013' ]   row.value->  1
            //row.key->  [ 'TX', '2014' ]   row.value->  1
            //row.key->  [ 'TX', '2015' ]   row.value->  1

            let obj={}
            obj[addr]=data.rows.length // This object contains unique address and its corresponding frequency in above query
            return obj

        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log('err-> ', err)
        })
    })

    return group_by_address

}).then(group_by_address=>{
    group_by_address.map(group=>{
        group.then(()=>{
            console.log('Grouped by address-> ', group)

            // Console logs related this section of code are shown below:

            //Grouped by address->  Promise { { CA: 2 } }

            //Grouped by address->  Promise { { NY: 4 } }

            //Grouped by address->  Promise { { CT: 4 } }

            //Grouped by address->  Promise { { TX: 4 } }
        })
    })
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log('err-> ', err)
})
```

Comment: +1 for thoroughness. That explanation makes sense. Are you saying what I want to do is not possible? Not through a combination of views, a complex reduce function, anything?

Comment: @JeffDiederiks I updated my answer with a possible solution. However, I'm not sure if it is the best idea. Maybe the best idea depends on the structure of the data inside the database.