# Sorting with the third parameter of keys array in couchdb

Tags: sorting, couchdb

I have the below view and the resulting dataset

```
A     B     C 
a    id1    10
b    id3    15
c    id4    17
a    id1    9
a    id2    9

function (doc) {

      emit([item,internalID,time],doc);
}
```

I am using **group_level=2** and and **startkey=['a']&endKey=['a',{}]**
This way i can get the result that i need. But the problem is I need the result to be sorted by the **column C** .Is this possible to do in couchDB ? or should i get the result set and sort it in the client side (Java or Browser JS in my case)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this reference](https://blog.couchbase.com/understanding-grouplevel-view-queries-compound-keys/) to understand how CouchDB sorting of *array keys*  or *compound keys* work.

Also, there is similar question whose [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49647616/3405291) might help you.