# Hyperldger fabric chaincode query to couchdb database

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm new to couchdb. I want to query to look for all records that meet folowing
a=first_parameter and b=sec_parameter and time=last five minutes
So in sql it would smth like this I guess

```
SELECT *ID* WHERE *A*=1 AND *B*=2 AND*time*>current_time-5
```

But how is it done in chaincode in hyperledger? Should I use composite key?
P.S. I looked in marbles example but there was only 1 parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You might emit *compound key* or *array key* inside map function of a view/index, like this:

```
emit([doc.A, doc.B, doc.time], doc._id)
```

Then, you can query the view/index like this:

```
GET db/_design/my_ddoc/_view/my_view?startkey=["1", "2", "${init_time}"]&endkey=["1", "2", "${final_time}"]
```

---

To understand how *array key* works on CouchDB, you might want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49647616/3405291).